# Group of order $1 5$ is cyclic.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Prove that any group of order $1 5$ is cyclic.

I am looking at a [solution here](http://www.math.rice.edu/~hassett/teaching/356spring04/solution.pdf) and I am confused why "there must be one orbit with five elements and three orbits with three elements" and "fixed points of this action are just elements of the center of $G.$ In our situation, it suffices to show that $G$ has just one fixed point $\ne e$."

Why are those the cases?

Comment: Due to the equation of classes and the act of conjugation of $G$ to where...?

Comment: @Dimitris I am not sure I understand your question?

Comment: Are you familiar with the class equation?

Comment: @Vladhagen yes I am.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In how many ways can you write $\;1+x_3+x_5=15\;,\;\;\Bbb N\ni x_3,x_5\ge 1\;$ , @user104235 ? Only with $\;x_5=5\;,\;\;x_3=9\;$ , with $\;x_i\;$ being the number of elements in the orbit of an element of order $\;i\;,\;\;i=3,5\;$ .

This is the reason there must be one orbit with five elements and three with three elements...

Comment: Oh okay, I understand it now. It seems more of a combinatorics question to me rather than group theory. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Well, yes...but it is based heavily in a group theoretic basic fact: actions of groups on sets and conjugation action.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

@user104235 you do all these in order to prove that you have an isomorphism $\Bbb Z_3\times \Bbb Z_5\to G$. Now by fixed points  they mean the Stabilizer of the action of $G$ to $G$,which is $Stab_{G}(G)=${$g\in G:gGg^{-1}=G$}=$Z(G)$. Just show that $Stab_{G}$ is not trivial and $Z(G)$ is also not trivial. And then use the class equation and show that there must be one orbit with five elements and three orbits with three elements, $|G|=|Z(G)|+\sum_{i=1}^{k} |Cl_{G}(x_i)|$ where $Cl_{G}(x_i)$ are the classes of $G$ that are not a uni set <=> $x_i$ are not in $Z(G)$

Answer (score 0):

Try to prove this general result :

if $G$ is a group of order $pq$ where $p$ and $q$ are primes such that $p \lt q$. If $p \nmid q-1$ , then $G$ is cyclic.

proving for the case order of $G$= 15 and proving to this general case are not too different.

Hint : use sylow theorem prove that $p$ sylow subgroup and $q$ sylow subgroups are unique. now its easy to find an element of order $pq$.

Comment: A small comment: all you need from sylow is that sylow subgroups exist, correct? This gives the existence of an element of order pq.

Comment: @connor no. we need the uniqueness of Sylow sub groups, so they will be normal.If two normal subgroups intersect only at identity, then every element of one normal subgroup will commute with the elements of the other. this is the crucial result used here.